# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError on Android devices with KitKat

Tags: android, noclassdeffounderror, android-4.4-kitkat, android-filterable

I am developing a app and at the moment the app crashes if I use Android KitKat but with Lollipop devices the app runs without crash. The error from LogCat:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: mypackage.utils.PlacesAutoCompleteAdapter$1
at mypackage.utils.PlacesAutoCompleteAdapter.getFilter(PlacesAutoCompleteAdapter.java:60)
at android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView.setAdapter(AutoCompleteTextView.java:635)
at mypackage.PlanRouteActivity.initializeLayout(PlanRouteActivity.java:148)
at mypackage.PlanRouteActivity.onCreate(PlanRouteActivity.java:83)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The class is inside the package of the error:

```
package mypackage.utils;

public class PlacesAutoCompleteAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> implements Filterable {

    private static final String TAG = "AutoCompleteAdapter";

    // Autocomplete Google Places
    private static final String PLACES_API_BASE = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place";
    private static final String TYPE_AUTOCOMPLETE = "/autocomplete";
    private static final String OUT_JSON = "/json";
    private static final String API_BROWSER_KEY = "AIzaSyD5JwM_VRieW2WmzPU_D4sl6YST0wuH6Io";

    private ArrayList<String> resultList;

    // Constructor
    public PlacesAutoCompleteAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return resultList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public String getItem(int index) {
        return resultList.get(index);
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        Filter filter = new Filter() {
            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
                if (constraint != null) {
                    // Retrieve the autocomplete results.
                    resultList = autocomplete(constraint.toString());

                    // Assign the data to the FilterResults
                    filterResults.values = resultList;
                    filterResults.count = resultList.size();
                }
                return filterResults;
            }

            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, Filter.FilterResults results) {
                if (results != null && results.count > 0) {
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                } else {
                    notifyDataSetInvalidated();
                }
            }
        };
        return filter;
    }

    /**
     * Autocomplete text input with Google places
     *
     * @param input: Text input from AutoCompleteTextView
     * @return ArrayList<String>
     */
    private ArrayList<String> autocomplete(String input) {
        ArrayList<String> resultList = null;

        HttpURLConnection conn = null;
        StringBuilder jsonResults = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(PLACES_API_BASE + TYPE_AUTOCOMPLETE + OUT_JSON);
            sb.append("?key=" + API_BROWSER_KEY);
            sb.append("&components;=country:de");
            sb.append("&input=" + URLEncoder.encode(input, "utf8"));

            URL url = new URL(sb.toString());
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream());

            // Load the results into a StringBuilder
            int read;
            char[] buff = new char[1024];
            while ((read = in.read(buff)) != -1) {
                jsonResults.append(buff, 0, read);
            }
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error processing Places API URL", e);
            return null;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error connecting to Places API", e);
            return null;
        } finally {
            if (conn != null) {
                conn.disconnect();
            }
        }

        try {
            // Create a JSON object hierarchy from the results
            JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonResults.toString());
            JSONArray predsJsonArray = jsonObj.getJSONArray("predictions");

            // Extract the Place descriptions from the results
            resultList = new ArrayList<String>(predsJsonArray.length());
            for (int i = 0; i < predsJsonArray.length(); i++) {
                resultList.add(predsJsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("description"));
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Cannot process JSON results", e);
        }

        return resultList;
    }
}
```

So again the app runs without crash using Android Lollipop, anyone an idea why it crashes on KitKat? My minSDKversion is 16, the targetSDKversion 21

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have observed this error in two situations previously:

**1.** I was using a physical device (i.e. not an emulator) that had Kitkat with ART enabled. When I ran the app on another Kitkat device with Dalvik runtime, the error seemed to have vanished.

**2.** The same problem arose due to a `.dex` build error which occurred when I shifted the SVN to another location. I deleted the old project entirely and created a new repository from the original project on my computer, and after rebuilding the project entirely the error did not reappear.

Comment: Thanks for your hints, I resolved the problem by changing         `multiDexEnabled = true` to `multiDexEnabled = false` in my build.gradle

Answer (score 4):

This can be happen if your application class is not instantiating double check your Menifest.xml for application class entry . And Your application class should look like:

```
public class AppController extends MultiDexApplication {
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

}

@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
    super.attachBaseContext(base);
    MultiDex.install(this);
}
```

}

add dependency `compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'`
add `multiDexEnabled = true` option to your build.gradle under default config:

```
defaultConfig {

    applicationId "com.app"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1"
    multiDexEnabled = true

}
```

Thats it.

Answer (score 0):

please check in gradle may be this code help you

dexOptions {
            javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
            preDexLibraries = false
        }