# Stickers Issue on Kitkat based Android Phones - QuickBlox SDK - Android

Tags: android, quickblox

I am working on an Android Application , Here I am working on chat functionality using [QuickBlox Chat](http://quickblox.com/developers/Android_XMPP_Chat_Sample). I have done with text , image chat till now . Now I am using [Stickers](http://quickblox.com/developers/Android_XMPP_Chat_Sample#Stickers) here .

Application is working fine on Lollipop based Android phones ,when I install it on KitKat based Android phones then it gives me following error in Logcat .

Here is the LogCat details :

```
    FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.musomeet, PID: 21520
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: vc908.stickerfactory.provider.b
at vc908.stickerfactory.provider.a.<init>(Unknown Source)
at vc908.stickerfactory.provider.a.d(Unknown Source)
at vc908.stickerfactory.provider.a.b(Unknown Source)
at vc908.stickerfactory.provider.a.a(Unknown Source)
at vc908.stickerfactory.provider.StickersProvider.a(Unknown Source)
at vc908.stickerfactory.provider.base.BaseContentProvider.onCreate(Unknown Source)
at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1638)
at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1609)
at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5008)
at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4582)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4522)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:151)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1381)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5292)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:824)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:640)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Build.gradle :

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'http://maven.stickerpipe.com/artifactory/stickerfactory' }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '22.0.1'

    defaultConfig {
        multiDexEnabled = false
        applicationId "com.xxx"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            applicationVariants.all { variant ->
                variant.outputs.each { output ->
                    def newName = output.outputFile.name
                    newName = newName.replace("app-release", "XXXX") 

                    output.outputFile = new File(output.outputFile.parent, newName)
                }
            }
        }
        debug {

            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            applicationVariants.all { variant ->
                variant.outputs.each { output ->
                    def newName = output.outputFile.name
                    newName = newName.replace("app-debug", "XXXX") 
                    output.outputFile = new File(output.outputFile.parent, newName)
                }
            }

        }
    }
}

repositories {
    maven {url "https://jitpack.io"}
}

dependencies {
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:1.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.2.0'
    compile 'me.drakeet.materialdialog:library:1.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:7.5.0'
    compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-youtube:v3-rev152-1.20.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.8.0'
    compile 'com.wdullaer:materialdatetimepicker:2.1.0'
    compile('com.github.ozodrukh:CircularReveal:1.1.1@aar') { transitive = true; }
    compile files('libs/quickblox-android-sdk-chat-2.4.jar')
    compile files('libs/quickblox-android-sdk-content-2.4.jar')
    compile('vc908.stickers:stickerfactory:0.2.2@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile files('libs/quickblox-android-sdk-messages-2.4.jar')
    compile files('libs/quickblox-android-sdk-core-2.4.jar')
    compile 'com.navercorp.pulltorefresh:library:3.2.3@aar'

    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.1.0'
    compile files('libs/androidsvg-1.2.2-beta-1.jar')
    compile files('libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar')
}
```

I have visited the official website of the Sticker library and Quickblox .I have visited many stackoverflow posts ,but no luck .

I don't know the exact fix of this issue .

Help me please .

Comment: Try to check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28914217/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-on-android-devices-with-kitkat).   

If you have multiDexEnabled = true, try change to multiDexEnabled = false in your build.gradle.   

Let us know, if you resolve your problem

Comment: It may help , I will try it and let you know .

Comment: @Dehimb have tried it but it is giving error while Building the App : Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.

Comment: please, provide your build.gradle file

Comment: I have included the build.gradle in above question .

Comment: It looks like you have a lot of libraries, so you need to use multiDex to avoid your error. Try to check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28914335/1229674) to get more information

Comment: I have checked the link , but it didn't work for me .

Answer (score 0):

Check into your manifest file if you are using the fallowing provider:

```
<provider
        android:name="vc908.stickerfactory.provider.StickersProvider"
        android:authorities="com.package_name.stickersProvider"
        android:exported="false"/>
```

Notice that android:authoritiesin the category tag must be replaced by your application's package name.

Comment: I have this in manifest file , without it stickers wont work even on Lollipop.

Comment: I got it, update your api level in your build.gradle and in your manifest file, you are using minSdkVersion 16, update it to minSdkVersion 14 and then sync your project.

Answer (score 0):

Please do this steps to enabled MultiDex.

```
public class YouApplication extends Application {

@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
    super.attachBaseContext(base);
    MultiDex.install(this);
  }
}
```

and modify your build.gradle like so:

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 22
buildToolsVersion "23.0.0"

     defaultConfig {
         minSdkVersion 14 //lower than 14 doesn't support multidex
         targetSdkVersion 22

         // Enabling multidex support.
         multiDexEnabled true
     }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
}
```

I was work 2 days for this error.
It is solved using multidex library.

It works for me.